# Undergraduate thesis credit is too expensive. Can I turn my thesis into 1-2 research papers & publish instead?

Tags: research-process, thesis, undergraduate

I’m a highly competitive (currently undergrad) student with the end goal of getting a position in academia. I’m about to graduate undergrad this summer; afterwards, I will do a Fulbright research grant, and try to apply for the top graduate schools.

Now due to the difficulties of the semester, I couldn’t finish my thesis in Spring 2021 but instead moved it to Summer 2021. Normally my scholarship (fully paid, public university) would cover tuition fees. However, this scholarship has just ended for me and will not cover the summer fees. And I’ve realized that the summer tuition for this one thesis credit — in which I’m getting minimal guidance from my busy advisor and am taking no classes — is $1,750.

I do have enough money saved to cover this, but it’s really a stretch. I’m kind of pissed really, paying this much money for literally a thesis credit is insane!! However I see my education as an investment. I really wanna be super competitive, and if doing a thesis is part of that, I’ll go hungry to make it happen.

But at the same time, I’m really doubting whether a thesis will be so much better than  turning my topic into 1-2 research papers. Plus I’m about to do a year long Fulbright research project, which I think will overshadow my senior thesis anyway?

Can you guys help me sort this out? Any advice is helpful!!! I’m so angry my public university is so exploitative and not sure if I should buy into that.

Comment: Can you take an incomplete for your spring credit and finish it over the summer?

Comment: Can you really get one or two research papers out of your (as yet unwritten) thesis, especially without good supervision? In my field, it's unusual for an undergrad thesis to contain anything novel. You might be underestimating the task.

Comment: Hmmm. Not sure how your university is "exploitative" after providing you a free education. Why the whine?

Comment: @Buffy The OP didn't say their university provided them a free education.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- ... "fully paid, public university" ...

Comment: @Buffy That doesn't imply the university provided the scholarship ...

Comment: If you don't finish the thesis will you still graduate? Everything in your future depends, most likely, on graduating.

Answer (score 6):

If you can publish your thesis in a journal, you should aim to do so regardless, and in addition to a thesis (if you choose to write one). Papers in a good journal are more highly regarded than a thesis.

Writing an undergrad thesis *might* increase your chances of grad school admission. If you have papers accepted into good journals, I doubt an undergrad thesis adds much to your application. However, most undergrad theses are not good enough for a journal publication (although yours might be).

Your thesis advisor is probably willing to help you continue your thesis research and/or turn it into journal papers even if you are not enrolled as a student.

Comment: +1 without support from a thesis advisor it's highly unlikely OP will successfully publish anything in a reputable journal.

Comment: The possibility that your advisor likely (?) does not care about your enrollment status is worth looking into, I'd think. They'd probably help you in any case, and you'd probably need their advice to manage to "conform" to publication standards in your field.

Comment: They are probably "willing" but not necessarily able.  They likely have a large workload.

Answer (score 2):

1. I would recommend you try to separate your anger from the practical problem you face. Even if in your judgment your university is screwing you over, I'd recommend you decide based solely on what you think is in your best interest.
2. Talk to your supervisor. They might be willing to help you supervise your thesis on an informal basis, and/or help you turn it into publications, even if you don't enroll. Conversely, even if you are willing to pay tuition, your supervisor's obligations likely ended with the spring semester, and they might have other plans for the summer.

   In either case, I'd recommend that you make a plan to have something concrete to show for your work, and that you consult with your supervisor. Good luck!

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

Several things about the question are unclear, but...

- If the thesis or corresponding credit is not required to get the degree, do not pay the $1750.  You will no benefit from paying it.
- Do publish your work *if* you can publish it in a reputable journal or conference.  Check with your advisor before you try this.
- Probably your advisor will be writing a letter for you.  If so, *do* finish the thesis and send it to your advisor.  Do not expect your advisor to help you finish the thesis; presumably, if you do not pay the $1750, the university will require your advisor to do something other than help you with your thesis.  This does not mean your advisor will not help you, but you should not expect it.

Comment: I would be very surprised if the university forbade the advisor from helping a student who is no longer formally enrolled. Especially during the summer, when faculty members often aren't even being paid.

Comment: Seconding @academic's objection: I'd be mildly amazed if a university or department therein attempted to prohibit faculty from assisting more-or-less students trying to do research. The question of enrollment is hard to see as critical, because none of my collaborators in my own work are "students enrolled at my university", etc.

Comment: @academic I did not say the advisor would be forbidden to help, simply that they would be required to do something else.  I am assuming that, whatever the workload model, the advising duties are part of it.  If advising is officially decreased, some other workload will be added.  We do not know if the faculty member is being paid during the summer, but the sort of faculty who advise theses are much more likely to be paid during the summer than those who do not advise theses.  If the faculty member is not being paid, then they should be able to do something other than advising.

Comment: @paulgarrett Again, I did not claim there was any prohibition.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist, understood. But/and a too-casual reader might misunderstand... (As usual...)... which might be the operational point... The longer I live, the less I seem to understand of people... :)